# Homeomorphism(topological spaces) version of Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $A$ , $B$ be topological spaces such that there for some subset $D$ of $B$ there is a homeomorphism form $A$ to $D$ and for some subset $E$ of $A$ there is a homeomorphism form $B$ to $E$ ; then must there exist a homeomorphism from $A$ to $B$ ?

Comment: If you simply google for [cantor bernstein topological](http://www.google.com/search?q=cantor+bernstein+topological), you will find some related stuff on internet. You will see several hits which answer your question (basically given the same asnwers as already osted here). [This post on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold) might also be interesting in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, consider $A=[0,1]$, $B=[0,1]\cup [2,3]$, $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]\cup [2,3] $ where
$$
f(x) = x
$$
and
$g(x): [0,1]\cup [2,3]\to [0,1]$ with $$g(x) = \frac{x}{6}$$

Comment: And $A$ and $B$ aren't homeomorphic since one is connected while the other isn't. (I was just about to write this exact example, so I thought I would add just a little bit.)

Answer (score 5):

Take $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ with their standard topologies in $\Bbb R$. Clearly they are not homeomorphic. But $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[\frac14,\frac13]$ and $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to itself.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a related property: are there non-homeomorphic $X$ and $Y$ such that there is a continuous bijection from $X$ to $Y$ and from $Y$ to $X$ as well?

And [this mathoverflow answers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30661/2060) shows that we can have such examples. They're a bit harder to come up with, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure that property is stronger, just different.  As far as I can tell, having a continuous bijection from X to Y does not imply an embedding of X into Y or vice versa.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed, I will edit it.

Comment: Thank you for your perspective on this. I believe this was a useful remark, and added to the overall discussion. +1