# Continuous surjections between non-homeomorphic spaces

Tags: general-topology, analysis

It is very easy to give examples of topological spaces $A$ and $B$ that are *not* homeomorphic to each other, with a continuous injection from $A$ to $B$, and a continuous injection from $B$ to $A$. See, for example $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$, as demonstrated in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1333276/825314) to a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333272/825314) on this forum, or this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/985911/825314). In other words, there exist topological spaces that do not satisfy the [Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257650/825314), when considering injective maps. I was wondering if this fails when considering surjective maps as well. That is, **given two topological spaces $A$ and $B$, if there exists a continuous surjection from $A$ to $B$, and a continuous surjection from $B$ to $A$, must $A$ and $B$ be homeomorphic to each other?** I think this shouldn't be true: there should be a simple counterexample, but I just can't find one! It would be great to have a counterexample for locally compact Hausdorff spaces, because I want to eventually understand problems with the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein property for $C^\star$ algebras...

Comment: $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^2$

Comment: $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\times\mathbb Q$

Comment: Oops, you wanted locally compact. OK, $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\times X$ where $X$ is a countably infinite compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30661/2060) on another maths stackexchange site is an almost duplicate. (It's stronger as its asks for two continuous bijections between non-homeomorphic spaces).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Aah, I see! The link you provided certainly answers my question, as well as provides a deeper understanding regarding my ulterior motive: CSB for topological spaces (and eventually C* Algebras, I hope...) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any two spaces which are countable, zero-dimensional, and not compact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simple example with $A$ and $B$  both compact!

$[0,2\pi]$ is not homeomorphic to $S^{1}$. The function $t \mapsto (\cos t,\sin t)$ is a  continuous surjection from $[0,2\pi]$ onto $S^{1}$, while the function $(x,y) \mapsto \pi (1+x)$ is a  continuous surjection from $S^{1}$ onto $[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $\Bbb R$ and $[0,\infty)$, with their usual topologies. They are not homeomorphic. But$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&[0,\infty)\\x&\mapsto&x^2\end{array}$$and$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,\infty)&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\x&\mapsto&x\sin(x)\end{array}$$are continuous and surjective.